# Project Euler, Number 2

Tags: javascript

So, I'm new to javascript, and - after completing the JS unit on codecademy, I'm working through Project Euler to get a better feel for the language. The problem is that I'm stuck on the second challenge. I feel pretty dumb at this point. The problem is to find the sum of all the even fibonacci numbers that are less than four million.

```
var fib = [1,2];
var stack = [];

for (i = 2; i < 4000000; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
}
```

That part works. I'm using JSFiddle, and it will print out the fibonacci sequence up to four million. The problem is the next part:

```
for (j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
    if (fib[i] % 2 === 0) {
        stack[j] = fib[i];
    }
}
```

I've tried that bit both inside and outside the for loop, and I can't figure this out. I have this feeling that I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :D

EDIT: I figured it out. Thank all of you! Here's what I did:

```
var total = 0;
var fib = [1, 2];

//In my first attempt, I made a set of the first 4,000,000
//fibonacci numbers. I just left the "4000000" there
//arbitrarily.
for (i = 2; i < 4000000; i++) {
    //This makes sure that I don't go over 4000000 in the array.
    if (fib[i - 1] < 4000000) {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    }
}

for (j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
    if (fib[j] % 2 === 0) {
        total += fib[j];
    }
}

alert(total);
```

And it printed out the correct answer! Woot.

Comment: You're using the index `i` inside the second loop.

Comment: Do you want the 4 million Fibonacci numbers or all Fibonacci numbers below 4 million? That's an important difference.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Do you get errors with a stack trace or just bad results?

Comment: The last time that I tried to run it, it crashed the browser. Kind of like a for loop with no limit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with this.

You say that you want to find the sum of all even fibonacci numbers? I don't get the point of putting the even results into another array and then dealing with them. Try something like this:

```
var fib = [1,2];
var result = 0;

for (i = 2; i < 4000000; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
}

for (j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
    if(fib[j] % 2 == 0){
        result = result + fib[j];
    }
}
```

Secondly,  you phrase it as "all even fibonacci numbers less than 4 million". Are you sure that they want the first 4 million fibonacci numbers, or the fibonacci numbers that are under 4 million?

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I think I realize my mistake. I created an array with the first 4,000,000 fibonacci numbers by mistake. That said, would something like this work?

    for (i = 2; i < (some number); i++){
        if ((i - 1) < 4000000) {
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
        }
    }

Comment: You could use this loop `for(i = 2; fib[i - 1] < 4000000; i++){ if (fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2] < 4000000 { fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[ i - 2]; } }`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
for (j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
    if (fib[i] % 2 === 0) {
        stack[j] = fib[i];
    }
}
```

with this

```
for (j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
    if (fib[j] % 2 === 0) {
        stack[j] = fib[i];
    }
}
```

And also, the problem says to only find fibonacci numbers below 4_000_000. There is no need to create 4 million fibonacci numbers. That would take forever. Try something smaller like 70.

Comment: You've still got a stray reference to `i`. Inside the if statement should probably be `stack.push(fib[j]);`.